# The touchpad on my Lenovo Legion Y520 started to automatically left click and hold. How can I fix this?

Tags: laptop, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Legion Y520 whose trackpad is now adding a  automatically left click and hold. What is happening? Can I fix it?

I bought it a couple of years ago and I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue but with a different Lenovo.
Sometimes gunk can get stuck in the pad, and that can keep it down. Also, i have had mechanical issues with Acer's that sometimes just click into place and don't come out.

Open the laptop and see. If you are afraid, take it to a specialist. Or you can just deal with it like me! :)